# Diagnose angina (chest pain) by taking Nitroglycerin

Tags: heart-disease, diagnostics, angina, tight-chest

Since nitroglycerin relieves the symptoms of angina (chest tightness, heavy feeling), why not to diagnose angina with Nitroglycerin?

If the pain goes away upon taking Nitroglycerin then you have angina, if not - something else, right?

Sure, if taken by a healthy person, even a small dose can cause dizziness and a big headache, but it still less expensive then a stress test (which costs about $700).

Why do doctors test angina with a stress test?

Comment: Can you examine for ST changes on an ECG when trying to diagnose with Nitrolingual spray at home? How do you know the pain isn't caused by oesophageal spasm which is also relieved?  Why would you want to self diagnose when you're not qualified? What's your life worth?